# Highlighter effect in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am developing an iPhone paining app in OpenGL ES. I want to create a highlighter tool that has the same effect of a real highlighter - lays a florescent color still showing what is behind. I am not able to come up with the correct combination of parameters for the glBlendFunc. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get this done. I would recommend using the alpha parameter for glColor4F:

```
glColor4f(0.97, 0.58, 0.12, 0.2);
```

(That will give you an orange highlighter) As for your blend function, just use:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: When I tried this the drawing underneath is getting heavily colorized. I am using a particle texture (a white dot) as brush. Will this be an issue?

Comment: Are you using GL Paint as an example? If so, try to turn your alpha really low and use:

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: Also if you are using the GLPaint sprite example it will draw thickly due to how many points are being drawn over and over in the same spot. You can also try and reduce the point count.

Comment: Yes, my starting point was GLPaint. The combination GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA with a very low alpha value is just changing the color of the strokes underneath to that of the highlighter. I also tried reducing the number of points drawn at one place.

Comment: I went through and couldn't get a version working with point sprites. It just takes too make dots painted over and over again. I changed to using GL_LINES and it works fine. You might want to consider having another rendering engine for highlighters, or looking into shaders if you can use OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying this for me. I tried reducing the opacity of the spirit itself to 2% and could get close to a highlighter effect. But again, if I use it 2 times on the same area, the drawing underneath fades off. I fully agree with your findings that point spirits is not the appropriate approach for this. What do you mean by using another rendering engine? Also, can you point me to any good resource to learn how to achieve this with shaders?